# Python - how to run the application and leave until it end?

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome

How can i run the application and leave instead of waiting when it will be ended? for example : `/var/tmp/runme.sh &`

Following code is working but it waits forever when Google Chrome will exit. how can i run Google Chrome but let my script exit?

```
import subprocess
import sys
import time

line = sys.argv[1]
print line

def kill_chrome():
  subprocess.call(['Taskkill', '/IM', 'chrome.exe', '/F'])

def run_chrome():
  subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', '--kiosk'])

def run_java():
  subprocess.call(['java', '-cp', 'C:/Python27/pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC3.jar;C:/Python27/jprint.jar', 'JPrint'])

try:
  if line.startswith("myjava:website"):
    print "Google Chrome - IDLE"
    run_chrome()

  elif line.startswith("myjava:a4"):
    print "Printing - JAVA"
    run_java()

  elif line.startswith("myjava:kill"):
    print "Killer"
    kill_chrome()

except Exception, err:
  print (err)
  pass

#time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family)? Looks like it does exactly what you want - runs app end does not waiting. You also pass arguments to the runned application.

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen( [ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe", "myarg"])
```

Without "myarg" it works too.

Comment: Popen works. But i always have a DOS window, its very annoying how to not show DOS window? e.g: `Popen(['Taskkill', '/IM', 'chrome.exe', '/F'])` . i tried pythonw.exe with myscript.pyw but still there is one annoying DOS windows pops up.

Comment: Do you mean windows terminal where you script is runned?

Comment: I have your code in: `C:\Python27\Paul.pyw`. Paul.pyw was executed by other applications such as VBS, BATCH, Java, etc etc. in that case it shows windows terminal.